# Random vertex selection

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, vertices, selection-tools

When ever I make selections in Blender to select some vertices it select some random vertices with it which is not even close.

I am not able to edit any vertex without looking at wire frame mode I edit after making sure that none other vertex are selected
Which is very time taking and frustrating and even create lots of misplacement I just use box select and this thing happen

- I tried to restart pc
- Tried to save as another blend file
- Tried to disable anti aliasing from preference>viewport

Comment: hello, could you please show a screenshot or even an animated gif of what's happening?

Comment: Hi and welcome :) Would you please [add at least an image or two](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/198663/edit) or [a gif](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers/964#964) showing the problem? This will help make your question a bit clearer for other users to understand. Thanks :) I've also taken the liberty of making a small edit to your post, to make it a little easier to read. Feel free to roll it back if you disagree with the change :)

Comment: Try to turn off antialiasing in the preferences (this is in viewport tab, quality section).